# Updating jquery datatables layout with MDL theme

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables, material-design-lite

There is this [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/xbvWQv) of how to do responsive data table with search filter and pagination. However, it is integrated only with Bootstrap. I checked `MDL` discussion forum but found no existing implementation of `MDL theme` for this kind of data table.

I am guessing I will have to write the integration myself since there seems to be none. I will appreciate pointers on how to integrate the dynamic `html elements` that are generated by `jquery datatables`. A simple step will be to change `Search` box theme from `Bootstrap` to `MDL` theme. I will appreciate pointers on how to do that basic step. I can then repeat it for pagination and drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

It is under tech review, but DataTables do have `MDL` theme, here is a small example:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.1.0/material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.material.min.css">
<section class="mdl-grid content">
  <div class="posts-container mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet
                  mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color-text--grey-800">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text" id="users_list">Users List</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600">
        <table id='users-activity-table' class="display">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Action</th>
              <th>User Name</th>
              <th>Time-stamp</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="usbody">
            <tr>
              <td> Login </td>
              <td> Mark Van-Helen2 </td>
              <td> Today </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> Logout </td>
              <td> Mark Van-Helen </td>
              <td> Also Today </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#users-activity-table').DataTable({
      columnDefs: [{
        targets: [0, 1, 2],
        className: 'mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'
      }]
    });
  });
</script>
```